# Cutting .tif 1853 maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

[image: Example of my problem]

[image]

I have the problem where my two map layers overlap each other, meaning that part of the map is hidden by the white area of the other layer. Thus I need to cut the excess white area to let the bottom layer show.

Comment: Try if setting white color as transparent from the layer properties helps.

Comment: which pixel value does that area have? (there's the value tool plugin for that) maybe if you set properties>transparency to that value the area below will reveal

Answer (score 1):

From what i see on your screenshots, you have lots of binary land registry tif files. Try creating a vrt to group them into only one layer.

To make vrt `gdalbuildvrt tif_images.vrt *.tif` can be useful should you go through the osgeo shell.

When you have done that, you will have only one config to do for all images. From what I see, white is 0 color and 1 is black color. You just need to pass your 0 color into a transparent color to get rid of your white areas.

Bonus will be that you can then put an aerial photo below and see your registry lines on top :)

Extra ref : http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html